# an easy python recursion program

Tags: python, recursion

here is my python code ,is a quite easy program ,but i  failed, thanks a lot

```py
def a(field, dict_data):
    key = field.split('.')
    if len(key) == 1:
        return dict_data[key[0]]
    a(".".join(key[1: len(key)]), dict_data[key[0]])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    d = dict({'a': dict({'b': dict({'c': dict({'d': "hello！"})})})})
    print(a("a.b.c.d", d))
```

my expected result is

```
'hello!'
```

but i got

```
'None'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return the value returned from the recursion

```
return a(".".join(key[1: len(key)]), dict_data[key[0]])
```

Currently it doesn't return anything so you get `None`.

Comment: @SummersKing I'm on the phone, I can't edit so much code. Just replace the last line in `a()`.

Comment: it's worded ! ~

Answer (score 0):

If you want you use for loop give this a try:

```
def a(field, dict_data):

  keys_list = field.split('.')
  for i,key in enumerate(keys_list):

    if key in dict_data.keys():
      dict_data=dict_data[key]

    if i == len(keys_list) - 1:
      print(dict_data) #return dict_data
```